# MYSQL - Select column from table2 equal to table1 column if table1 column not null

Tags: mysql

I want to retrive data from table1's column1 and table2's column2 with table2's column1 equal to table1's column3 and table1's column2 equal to some condition. But if table1's column2 is null just table1's column1 with table1's column2 equal to some condition.

For example

```
TABLE1
BOOKNAME  BOOKNO READERNO 
--------------------------
NAME1     1      NULL     
NAME2     2      1
NAME3     3      2
NAME4     4      NULL
```

```
TABLE2
READERNO  READERNAME 
---------------------
1         JHON DOE    
2         JANE DOE
```

Desired results

WHERE BOOKNO = 1

```
BOOKNAME  READERNAME 
---------------------
NAME1     NULL
```

WHERE BOOKNO = 2

```
BOOKNAME  READERNAME 
---------------------
NAME2     JHON DOE
```

I hope I was clear

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want a `left join`?

```
select t1.bookname, t2.readername
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.readerno = t1.readerno
where t1.bookname = 1
```